# svn:// not working but http:// is

Tags: apache, svn, debian

If I try to checkout a repo from a Debian server via `svn://example.com/svn/repo` I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'svn://example.com/svn/repo'
No repository found in 'svn://example.com/svn/repo'
```

I get the same same error when trying to checkout from the server via the shell.

It works if I use "http://example.com/svn/repo" and the repo definitely exists.

svnserve is running as a daemon listening on port 3690 (UDP/TCP).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you are accessing the wrong URL. Note that the path component of the `svn://` URL (`srv/repo` in your case) is interpreted relative to what you pass to the `-r` argument of `svnserve`.

Other possible reasons are:

- svnserve is not configured properly,
- there is a firewall in the way.

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been already answered but for future references, enabling port 3690 in firewall worked for me.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3690/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3690/udp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```